# Aws Ruby SDK credentials from file

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I would like to store my credentials in `~/.aws/credentials` and not in environmental variables, but I am struggling.

To load the credentials I use (from [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/SharedCredentials.html#credentials-instance_method))

```
credentials = Aws::SharedCredentials.new({region: 'myregion', profile_name: 'myprofile'})
```

My `~/.aws/credentials` is

```
[myprofile]
AWS_ACCESS_KEY = XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
AWS_SECRET_KEY = YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY
```

My `~/.aws/config` is

```
[myprofile]
output = json
region = myregion
```

I then define a resource with

```
aws = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(region: 'eu....', credentials: credentials)
```

but if I try for example

```
aws.instances.first
```

I get the error `Error: #<Aws::Errors::MissingCredentialsError: unable to sign request without credentials set>`

Everything works if I hard code the keys

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/fd0373ea9765e03a64697785b8b1c2229d66ec67/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/credential_provider_chain.rb#L45) aws loads credentials automatically only from ENV.

You can create credentials with custom attributes.

```
credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(AWS_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_SECRET_KEY)
aws = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(region: 'eu-central-1', credentials: credentials)
```

In your specific case, it seems there is [no way](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ruby/blob/fd0373ea9765e03a64697785b8b1c2229d66ec67/gems/aws-sdk-core/lib/aws-sdk-core/shared_credentials.rb#L26) to pass custom credentials to `SharedCredentials`.

Comment: I ended up parsing the file and manually create the `Aws::Credentials`

Answer (score 0):

If you just do
`credentials = Aws::SharedCredentials.new()`
it loads the `default` profile. You should be able to load `myprofile` by passing in `:profile_name` as an option.

I don't know if you can also override the region though. You might want to try to loose that option, see how it works.

Comment: It does not work. That is the first thing I tried. It does not give any error, but credentials are not loaded